# Android - Unable to share both Url and Image on facebook wall using intent

Tags: android, facebook, image, android-intent

I need to share url and image on facebook wall using intent. If I'm sharing both, only image is getting shared because in intent setype I'm using "image/*". Below are the code snippet

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sample_image.png";            
File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);             
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "URL goes here"); 
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

I need to share both url and image. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/b099l3/FacebookImageShareIntent

Comment: Hi i need to post both Url and Image on facebook. Can u pls help me?